# What combination of PS filters can achieve this?

Tags: photoshop-effects, filter

Is it possible to achieve this effect using a few filter combinations in Photoshop?

[image]
http://cl.ly/183m2V253O1U2u0j2642

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible for PhotoShop filters to magically create nice artistic illustrations for you.

Comment: oh i must disagree.. i think combining a few techniques  CAN produce a few ( not many ) nice "illustrative" effects : http://cl.ly/1u3c2Z2P1k0w1a2E000N

Comment: Well, they can assist with effects, but they can not typically CREATE nice illustrations.

Comment: In other words, your sample illustration is something someone drew.

Comment: just using 2 filters and 1 adjustment layer i managed to bang out this: http://cl.ly/2y1Z0R392V01360T1W0n - .. albeit not great.. but perhaps someone has already done something close?

Comment: The challenge is that it's hard for a software algorithm to make the organic, artistic decisions that are in the example you show. The line weight, repetition, varying angles, shape forms, etc, were all created with an artistic eye...something PhotoShop filters haven't quite mastered. I think a good example of that are some of the 'engraving' filters out there. They come close...and impressively so, but you can always tell it was a computer process rather than an actual engraver that created the image.

Comment: @Artur, the additional images you are linking to are in no way even close to the original **illustration**. Note all your additional images have basic patterns from running filters. The original image has directional stripes in each area of the image... it's an illustrator, not a filtered photo. **There's no magic button which works instead of having artistic talent**.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too hard for you to color a drawing like that using Photoshop (I would recommend illustrator for this vectorial style, but any soft is good), but you would first need to have the outlines. If you have access to a tablet, you can try doing some lines and filling the spaces using colors and gradients. I would have a top layer for the outlines (transparent), and draw "boxes" of colors in layers behind it with the pen tool (colouring them using blending options). Another option, but with much more work I think, would be to use patterns (you can make them yourself) and apply those patterns to the color layers. That way you don't have to draw every single line with the tablet (or mouse, mouse is good too!)